# Clustering setups?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am new in ejabberd clustering setup i tried ejabberd cluster setup past one week but till i did not get it.
1.After clustering setup i got the output like running db nodes =             ['ejabberd@first.example.com','ejabberd@second.example.com'] still now fine.

1. After that i login into PSI+ client and login credtials username:one@first.example.com then password:xxxxx.
2. Then i stopped ejabberd@first.example.com node my PSI+ client also down.
3. So why its not automatically connect with my second server ejabberd@second.example.com
4. Then how will i achieve ejabberd clustering suppose if one node is crash another node is manitain the connection  automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set up one cluster, or federate two clusters? If just one cluster, they should share the same domain (either first.example.com or second.example.com).

Also, when there's a node failure, your client must reconnect (not sure what PSI does), and you need to have all nodes in your cluster behind a VIP so the reconnect attempt will find the next available node.

Comment: i follow this link steps only http://chad.ill.ac/post/35967173942/easy-ejabberd-clustering-guide-mnesia-mysql i didnot do anything in s2s and router erl files.In ejabberd clustering coding side i didnot do anything only i followed that link steps after that i got two running db.so what should i do for reconnect attempt for next available node.